# European travel, Schengen 90/180 question and UK visa questions

Tags: uk, schengen

I am a US citizen considering a job with a UK company.  The duration of the job will be about one year and have me traveling in and out of UK/Schengen area.  I will be in the UK on a Tier 5 visa and my employer is working out the details of my time in the Schengen area.  My wife and one year old son (both US citizens) will be traveling with me.  We are trying to work out their travel and have a question.

We undersatand the 90/180 day rule and have calculated the time we will be in the Schengen area very carefully.  January 14 will be their 90th day in Schengen as well as their 180th day since first entering.  My question is what happens on January 15?  It will be day one of a new 90/180.  Can they just continue on with their travels or will they need to leave the area on the 14th and re-enter on the 15th to "restart" their 180 day counter?  Could they just visit a local consulate to get a new stamp?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Welcome to [travel.se]. Our format works best when each posting contains a single carefully focused question. You will get better answers by splitting your questions into two separate posts.

Comment: The UK limit is six months per visit.  There's no rule about a rolling year.  But the Schengen 180-day period *is* a rolling period, so the "first day of another period" reasoning does not work.  It used to work that way, but it changed several years ago.  See [How does the Schengen 90/180 rule work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13183/19400)

Comment: On the other hand, the Schengen 90/180 rule is based on a rolling period. On any day they are present in the area, they must not have been present more that 89 days in the preceding 179.

Comment: OK.  Let's just focus on the Schengen part of out travel then.  As per the 90/180 day rule as it was provided to me when I asked a question via the Schengen website the 180 days begins the first day someone enters the area and ends 180 days later.  In that time we can travel no more than 90 days in the area.  In our situation the 90th travel day is the same day as the 180th day since entering.  How do we begin a new 180 days?  do we have to leave the area and come back?  If so will one day be enough?  Essentially, we need to know what happens on January 15.

Comment: Read the linked question.  The information you have is incorrect or misleading.  On every single day of presence, you must look at the preceding 179 days.  In other words, a new 180-day period begins every day at midnight.  What happens on January 15th: nothing, since at least one of the 90 days is more than 180 days earlier.  The day on which they'll need to leave depends on how many of the days of presence in the Schengen area were more than 90 days before the 15th and how many were less than 90 days before.  In no case can they spend more than 90 consecutive days in the Schengen area.

Comment: Because the calculation is based on days of presence, leaving the Schengen area and coming back never helps unless you stay away long enough to bring your total days of presence in the area under 90.  For example, if you stay for 85 consecutive days and then leave for less than 90 days, your next stay cannot be longer than 5 days.  If you leave for more than 90 days then your next stay can be up to 90 days.  Which "Schengen website" did you ask on, by the way? There are lots of unofficial sites that look official and give inaccurate information.

Comment: There is an official calculator.  Perhaps it will help you understand how the rule works: https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm

Comment: Thanks phoog.  This is a lot to wrap our brains around.  We just want to make sure we know what we are getting into before I commit to the job.  Would you be willing to let me send you a personal message with exactly what we are dealing with as far as travel?  And how do I send a personal message?  Also, is there such a thing as a long stay visa for travel?

Comment: There are no private messages on this site. You can come into the chat, where there are often people able to help you. You do need some rep, if you do get the message you do not have enough yet, post that here and likely you get helped to get in. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here

Comment: @Uly sorry, I didn't see that comment before today because of the lack of "@" before my name. As Willeke notes, there are no personal messages. If you want to post the travel dates (you can edit your question or ask a new one), you might be able to get some advice. There are no long-stay visas for *travel,* sadly, but some countries do have long-stay visas for the "economically inactive." As I understand these typically require a (temporary) address in the country; there's no solution for those who want to spend, for example, two weeks in each of seven Schengen countries.

Answer (score 2):

> As I see it, the Original Poster (OP) is making a sincere and diligent
>   attempt to comply with the Schengen regulations about overstaying.
>
> The rule itself is fundamentally straight-forward… Briefly a person
>   becomes an overstayer on their 91st consecutive  day inside the zone. 
>   The day count is measured from the present day and extending back for
>   180 days.
>
> The OP is struggling because he essentially has something
>   ass-about-face. He asks…
>
> *How do we begin a new 180 days?*
>
> And the answer is: you don’t.  What’s happened here is that the OP has
>   it that the 180 period is a forward looking time window.  So from that
>   viewpoint it seems natural that a person can ‘renew’ their 180 days
>   and thereby spend more time in the zone.  But it doesn’t work like
>   that.  You cannot ‘renew’ or ‘refresh’ it.
>
> As alluded to above, the 180 day period is a backward-looking time
>   window.  For any given day, you look backward into the previous 180
>   days (present day included) and count the number of days you were in
>   the Schengen zone.  If that number exceeds 90, you’re an overstayer
>   plain and simple.  This rule holds true even for non-visa nationals
>   like Americans, Canadians, and so on.
>
> Schengen overstayers get caught on their way out when they encounter
>   an exit check. Sometimes the authorities don’t notice and other times
>   they do. If a person gets caught, the authorities have a menu where
>   they can select any of the following: scolding, fines, incarceration,
>   and expulsion.
>
> A possible source of confusion lies in the way other regulatory
>   schemes work, like the UK. There, when your ‘visa’ expires, you need
>   to ‘channel hop’ to get a new 6 months (as long as you can pass the
>   landing interview).

[Reference](https://gayotfow.wordpress.com/2018/03/20/the-schengen-90-180-rule-redux/)

Comment: Which, among others means that if day 180 from the moment you arrived is the day 90 of you stay inside the Zone, then tomorrow again will be day at most 90.

Comment: Err, no.  If the 90 days in-zone are the most recent 90, then tomorrow will be the 91st day in the zone, in its 180-day rear-facing window.

Comment: Thanks you all for the responses.  I was indeed interpreting it wrong.  I was looking forward not backwards.  This confusion stemmed from a "clarification" of the rules I received when submitting a question to europa.eu.  In part of their response to me they state, "The 90 days would ‘automatically renewed’ the moment the period of 180 days expires."  This is where I got the idea that once my original 180 day was through it would reset to another 180.  Poor wording on their part and poor interpretation on my part.    Thanks to everyone for the clarification.

Comment: @Uly it used to work like that: distinct periods of 180 days.  For some countries' citizens, it still works that way because of bilateral agreements.  But for most, including US citizens, you must look at every 180-day period (1 Jan through 29 June, 2 Jan through 30 June, etc.).